# UrlFetchApp query a spreadsheet with gviz

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to query a spreadsheet with gviz (Google Visualization), using UrlFetchApp, but no result so far.

Could you help me to fix this code?
(the query Url works fine in the browser)

```
function queryTest() {
  var onlyforscope = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var template = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%s/gviz/tq?gid=%s&tq=select C,E,K,M,N,O where C contains '%s'";
  var query = Utilities.formatString(template, docId, sheetId, value);
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query, param).getContentText();
//  var j = JSON.parse(r);
  Logger.log(r);  
  return;
}
```

Thanks in advance, Fausto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it was trivial, though hard to find out for me
the required scope is Drive !!!
I just add this line and it worked

```
  var onlyforscope = DriveApp.getRootFolder();﻿
```